# PHP undefined offset in array looping

Tags: php, undefined, offset

I have simple codes down below :

```
   $i = 0;    
    $array = array('name','email','address');

    while ($array[$i]) {
    echo "$array[$i]<br>";

    $i++;
    }
```

My problem : After echoing name, email, address without problem, It generates an error message "Undefined offset: 3".
What is I insist to use WHILE loop instead of IF condition. How to deal with the error.
Thank you

Comment: use :`while (isset($array[$i])) {` to solve your problem. you should search and try  before asking.

Comment: Thank you Suchit kumar my bro , you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array('name','email','address');
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($array);$i++) {
    echo "$array[$i]<br>";
}
?>
```